# integral of product vs product of integral

Tags: calculus

I would like to show that
$$
\int_X a(x) dx\cdot \int_X b(x)dx \geq \int_X a(x)b(x)dx
$$
when $0\leq b(x) \leq 1$ and $0\leq a(x) < C$ for some finite $C$.

Is this even true? And if so, what might be a technique to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Take $b(x)=1$. Then your inequality becomes
$$
\int_Xa(x)dx\cdot Vol(X)\ge \int_Xa(x)dx
$$
which clearly does not hold if $Vol(X)$ is less than $1$. True inequalities should be dimensionally correct, and yours is not.

Comment: Thanks. this is a great counterexample.